# Como hacer una variable con IN

Tags: sql-server, variables

Por favor me pueden ayudar diciendo si hay una manera de hacer una variable de la siguiente manera en SQL o que otra opcción existe para hacerla. Ya que cuando la ejecuto me saca error.

Ejemplo tengo el siguiente query:

```
DECLARE @PeriodoAc Char(7) = '2023-02'
,@fechaAC DATETIME = '2023-02-28'
DECLARE @PeriodoAn TABLE (Periodo VARCHAR(7))
INSERT INTO @PeriodoAn VALUES('2021-06')
INSERT INTO @PeriodoAn VALUES('2022-06')  SELECT * FROM @PeriodoAN
(Line 93) SELECT
....
...
...
...
..
WHERE Periodo IN ((SELECT * FROM @PeriodoAn),@PeriodoAc)
Si se viera el código tendria que ser algo así Where Periodo IN ('2021-6','2022-06','2023-02')
```

Me saca el siguiente Error
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 93
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Nota: No copio todo el Query ya que es demasiado extenso

Comment: Eso no se puede no tiene sentido :/, más bien tendrias que hacer una tabla temporal para guardar esos 2 valores o almacenarlos por separado

Comment: Jorge y como seria con una tabla temporal?
Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si entiendo el problema, creo que se resolvería con un: `where Periodo in (select Periodo from @PeriodoAn union select @PeriodoAc)`

Answer (score 2):

pero todo depende para que lo quieres

```
DECLARE @Periodo TABLE
(Periodo VARCHAR(7))

INSERT INTO @Periodo VALUES('2021-06')
INSERT INTO @Periodo VALUES('2022-06')

SELECT * FROM @Periodo
```

Comment: Requiero hacer una consulta posterior donde va de la siguiente manera.

.....
Where Periodo = (@Periodo)

En este caso @Periodo = ('2021-06','2022-06')
Pero con el tiempo tendre que ir adicionando más periodos

Comment: podrías hacer:
... WHERE Perdiodo IN (SELECT Periodo from @Periodo)

Comment: Me arroja este error si lo hago como una sub consulta dentro del Where

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: si pusiste "IN", si pones igual ( = ) va a marcar ese error

Comment: @MrDonPh0x 

El Query que tengo es el siguiente.

DECLARE arrobaPeriodo TABLE (Periodo VARCHAR(7))
INSERT INTO arrobaPeriodo VALUES('2021-06')
INSERT INTO arrobaPeriodo VALUES('2022-06')

SELECT     (Linea 93)
....
....
...
WHERE Periodo IN ((SELECT * FROM arrobaPeriodo))

Me saca el siguiente error
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 93
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: me suena a que el error no está ahí, sino mas arriba
puedes agregar tu query  completo a la pregunta?

Comment: tienes que insertar PeriodoAc en la  tablaPeriodoAn

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes SQL Server 2016 o superior puedes usar "STRING_SPLIT

en donde guardas todos los valores en una variable y después ya la puedes leer como una tabla.

```
Declare @Periodos nvarchar(50) = '2021-06,2022-06'

select value from STRING_SPLIT(@Periodos,',')
```

Comment: No me permite hacerlo de esa manera ya que el SQL Server que tengo es menor a 2016

Comment: Listo ya puse el Query que me saca error, gracias por tu ayuda